# Free to wrong pool 2608aa8 not 6d3fe8 at test.pl

Tags: windows, perl, fork

Following is my code:

```
sub test_ms {

    my $coderef1 = shift;
    my $coderef2 = shift;

    if (fork() == 0) {
        &$coderef1;
        exit;
    }
    &$coderef2;
}
```

When I am running this, I am getting the error as

> *Free to wrong pool 2608aa8 not 6d3fe8 at test.pl*

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What are you passing _in_ to your subroutine?

Comment: Try upgrading your perl to a newer version.

Comment: My perl version is 5.14.

Comment: I am passing this: 
my $coderef1  = sub { $Excel->Run('login') };

Comment: Are you using Windows? Because using fork on Windows will not work as expected.

Comment: Yes, I am using Win7. Is there any other way by which this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

[perlfork](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html) says

> On Windows fork() system call is not available

That's why it's not working as expected for you. Try using `Win32::Process::Create`.

See:

- [What is the difference between Windows fork and Unix fork?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=588994)
- [A Great little summary of issues with fork on Windows](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MOB/Forks-Super-0.63/README.windows)
- [Mr. Peabody Explains fork()](http://users.telenet.be/bartl/classicperl/fork/all.html)

Answer (score 0):

That message means a scalar (or array or ...) allocated by one thread (or interpreter?) was freed by another. `fork` creates threads, not processes on Windows. It's probably because the object in `$Excel` is not safe to pass between threads. Create `$Excel` in the thread in which you are going to use it.